# Replacing reinterpret_cast by memcpy

Tags: c++, memcpy

I've got some legacy code containing the following line of code:

```cpp
uint16_t* data = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(array_.data()); // #1
```

With `array_` of type `std::vector`. So far, I understood that we store into data a pointer to the first element of the vector, and we tell the compiler to consider it as an uint16_t.

For some reasons, I'm looking to replace the `reinterpret_cast` by a `memcpy`.

I've come along with the following replacement lines:

```cpp
uint16_t* data;
memcpy(&data, typed_array_.data(), bytes_per_elem); // #2
```

With `bytes_per_elem` the size in bytes of vector elements.

I'm not very fluent with the use of `reinterpret_cast` and `memcpy`, so I'd like to know, can I consider #1 and #2 as equivalent?

Comment: what type of vector is it? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Your "replacement" uses an uninitialized pointer, and will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: And ***why*** do you need "to replace the reinterpret_cast by a memcpy"? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: As you write `uint16_t* data = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(array_.data());` stores a pointer to the vectors first element in `data`. That not the same as copying the vectors elements, it merely stores a pointer to first element. Its unclear why you would consider the two equivalent (even if #2 would be correct).

Comment: this cannot be answered thourouhly without knowing what `array_` is and what you will do with `data`

Comment: It appears that on #1, my compiler is warning me about potential cast-alignment problems. That's the reason why i'm looking to store the pointer to the vector first element in another way.
It seems that my vector is a vector of uint8_t.

Comment: alignment means the type of the vectors elements is relevant. Why do you hide this information from us?

Comment: "For some reasons" such as what? `memcpy()` of an address range onto itself accomplishes exactly nothing. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Questions with one-word answers (e.g. "yes" or "no") are not interesting/useful. Your question might become interesting if you asked how to accomplish [your real goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), rather asking if your flawed solution is equivalent.

Comment: the warning hints you at an issue of dereferencing the pointer obtained from the reinterpret_cast. The reinterpret_cast itself isnt the issue. Hence merely replacing the cast isnt going to fix any issue in the code

Comment: Downvote for what? this is a VALID question.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing how the vector is declared and how it's filled with values. While this cast is suspicious, don't rush to change code that already works.

Comment: Why memcpy? at least in c++ you should use `std::copy` (it is NOT slower). Also note with casts like this you will lose ALL size information (which probably is going to be a source of bugs somewhere else). Also what IS the type contained in the original vector?

Comment: one issue with the question that causes repeated confusion is that its not obvious whether you want #2 to copy the value of the pointer to `data`, that would be not consistent with using `bytes_per_elem` as number of bytes to copy nor with usnig the vectors data as source pointer, OR if you want it to copy the elements in the array, in that case `&data` is the wrong destination and `bytes_per_elem` is again wrong. And in both cases it is not obvious what this change is supposed to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can i consider #1 and #2 as equivalent ?

No, the `#2` code looks very invalid. It tries to interpret the data stored in a vector as a pointer value to uint16_t. Which the first interprets the data stored in the vector as values of uint16_t, not a pointer value.

I guess you probably meant to allocate the memory to store the actual data:

```
// assuming std::vector<uint8_t> array_;
std::vector<uint16_t> data(array_.size() / sizeof(uint16_t));
memcpy(data.data(), array_.data(), array_.size());
```

But it would be much better to do the actual conversion, like:

```
// assuming std::vector<uint8_t> array_;
std::vector<uint16_t> data(array_.size() / sizeof(uint16_t));
for (size_t i = 0; i < array_.size(); i += 2) {
    // little endian or big endian?
    data[i / 2] = array_[i] << 8 | array_[i + 1];
}
```

Consider researching strict aliasing rules, `reinterpret_cast`, how does pointers differ from values, what is `&` operator in C++, `<bit>`, `std::byte`, `std::bit_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

The code using `reinterpret_cast` and the replacement code using `memcpy` are NOT equivalent.

The line using `reinterpret_cast` does not perform any data copying; it simply changes the type of the pointer. Both pointers are pointing to the same memory location.

The line using `memcpy()` is attempting to copy data from the memory location which `typed_array_.data()` is pointing at, to the memory location occupied by `data` itself, not to where `data` is pointing at (which is nowhere).

Note that the destination pointer `data` is uninitialized, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: i overlooked this at first too, the destination pointer is `&data` not `data`

Comment: The behavior of the 2nd code is *undefined* only if `bytes_per_elem > sizeof(uint16_t*)`, or if the byte size of the vector's data is `< bytes_per_elem`.  The code *following* the 2nd code will be undefined only if the `vector`'s data does not represent a pointer, and `data` is dereferenced after being copied into. But since we don't know for sure what is actually in the `vector`, we can only make (educated) guesses...

Answer (score -2):

Even if we wouldn t consider your errors, the two snippets act differently. The first, it s nothing more than pointer type conversion. In C converting from integral type to pointer, pointer to integral type or from pointer to pointer of different type is just fine, in C++ it's not. Here comes `reinterpret_cast`, which force the compiler to do that operation. Such operation may be unsafe, that's why the compiler asks you to explicitly declare the conversion. In the second example there is an error, you just declared the pointer but it is not initialized. To initialize the pointer you have three ways: declaring an array big enough(probably the worst), declaring an array with the `new[]` operator (remember you must free the memory with `delete[]`), or declaring a `std::vector<uint16_t>` and reserve the needed space. That said, in the memcpy call, the last parameter is the total number of bytes, not the bytes per element